# C# expand array to be arguments

Tags: c#

```cs
void foo(int one, int two) {
}

public static void Main(string[] args) {
  var bar = new int[] { 1, 2 };
  foo(params bar);
}
```

What's the correct syntax to deconstruct the bar array and pass it as the arguments to the foo method?

In some other languages you can use a splat operator `foo(...bar)` or an unpack operator `foo(*bar)`.

How can I do it in C#?

Comment: Since you know `foo` has two arguments, you could just write `foo(bar[0], bar[1])`, which is likely to be more efficient than anything involving Reflection.

Comment: if foo is `void foo(params int[] vals)`, then you can call it either with an array or with arguments, and `foo(bar);` will work then

Comment: @MichaelLiu there's no way to just expand it?

Comment: @minseong there's no way to expand it and the reason is that C# is a *statically typed* language. There's no way the compiler can guarantee that the array objects will all match the amount and type of the parameter list in order. Reflection can achieve your goal but that will introduce more overhead than necessary.

Comment: @maksymiuk ~~I don't see why the compiler can't guarantee that~~ — okay of course, the compiler couldn't check if the _number_  of items in the array matches any argument specification

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't an equivalent function in C#. Each argument has to be passed individually.

There are, of course, work arounds that you likely already know. You could declare an overload for your function that would accept an array and call the original function using the first two inputs. The other alternative that I can think of is to declare the function parameter with the params keyword so that it could receive an array or multiple conma-separated  elements when called.

```
void foo(params int[] numbers)
{   // TODO: Validate numbers length
    int one = numbers[0];
    int two = numbers[1];
}
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    var bar = new int[] { 1, 2 };
    // both valid function calls below
    foo(bar);
    foo(bar[0], bar[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use Reflection for such purpose.
Here is example snippet on your example method:

```
class MainClass
{
    void foo(int one, int two)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(one + two);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var myInstance = new MainClass();

        var bar = new object[] { 1, 2 };
        var method = myInstance.GetType().GetMethod(nameof(MainClass.foo), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
            ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"Method '{nameof(MainClass.foo)}' not found");
        method.Invoke(myInstance, bar) ;
    }
}
```